# Maven 2.xx dependency override in child

Tags: maven, dependencies

Are there **any** way to override a dependecy version in child project over parent's version?

Parent pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
<dependency>
```

Child pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
<dependency>
```

I did not find any working articles on this subject.

Comment: AFAIK, though from Maven 3.x.x, child settings override parent settings. What's displayed for `spring-core` if you perform `mvn help:effective-pom` in the child project?

Comment: What does `mvn dependency:tree` says for your module? Apart from that: Really using Maven 2?

Comment: Effective pom both says from eclipse and command line that the child is using the parents version 3.1.1 instead of the overwritten version. The project is legacy....have to use maven2.